# Get error `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm trying to use iCloud key-value using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class. But when I try to get value by specified key, I get an error

`[<NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore 0x6000002983d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "some_key"`

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the bad key?  Look up what makes a valid key. See where they conflict.

Comment: Do I have to define this keys in my console? I didn't find any info about this

Answer (score 9):

Use:

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set(yourValue, forKey: "your.key")`

instead of

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.setValue(yourValue, forKey: "your.key")`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're getting this error if the value you're trying to store is not exposed to the objective-c runtime (like an optional value type for instance). Try converting your Int/Double/etc to a non-optional NSNumber and then retrieving it via object(forKey:) instead.